# How to put elements into another (jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the markup I have on the page, quite literally:

```
data-eng="text"data-eng="text"data-eng="text"data-fr="text"data-fr="text"data-fr="text"data-ger="text"data-ger="text"data-ger="text"
```

And this is what I need from the markup above:

```
<a data-eng="text" data-fr="text" data-ger="text"></a>
<a data-eng="text" data-fr="text" data-ger="text"></a>
<a data-eng="text" data-fr="text" data-ger="text"></a>
```

As you can see, the number of rows I need to make (anchors links) depends on how many of the same data-attribute there are in the original markup. E.g.

```
data-eng="text"data-eng="text"data-eng="text"data-fr="text"data-fr="text"data-fr="text"data-ger="text"data-ger="text"data-ger="text"
```

would produce

```
<a data-eng="text" data-fr="text" data-ger="text"></a>
<a data-eng="text" data-fr="text" data-ger="text"></a>
<a data-eng="text" data-fr="text" data-ger="text"></a>
```

whereas

```
data-eng="text"data-fr="text"data-ger="text"
```

would produce

```
<a data-eng="text" data-fr="text" data-ger="text"></a>
```

I'm kinda stumped as to how to approach this, could anyone show me an example code that would work for this? I have tried .wrap and .append but with no luck, I can't seem to accomplish the rows I need.

Comment: This **markup** how are you getting it? In what format? How is it stored? Where is it stored? I find it weird handling it as a string.

Comment: @Grimbode its just the output by a CMS, and unfortunately it has difficulty rendering in another way

Comment: Far better to fix the output into something with some structure than to have chronic problems with current format

Comment: @charlietfl I appreciate that, I'm only asking as a last resort :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think your approach is a great idea, but sometimes hacks are necessary.  One approach you could take for this is running a regex against it.

[Something like this fiddle should work.](http://jsfiddle.net/dj5qbvbk/)

You'll probably need to modify it for your specific usecase, but this should be enough to get you started :)

Here the code.  Basically we regex for the 3 patterns and then draw as many links as the minimum pattern array length.  (the match returns and array of matches or null when no matches.  you'll probably want to add some error checking as well.)

```
var cmsOut = 'data-eng="text"data-eng="text"data-eng="text"data-fr="text"data-fr="text"data-fr="text"data-ger="text"data-ger="text"data-ger="text"';

var engDetector = cmsOut.match(/data-eng="text"/g);
var frDetector  = cmsOut.match(/data-fr="text"/g);
var gerDetector = cmsOut.match(/data-ger="text"/g);


var htmlOut = '';
for(i=0;i<engDetector.length;i++){
    if(engDetector[i] && frDetector[i] && gerDetector[i]){
        htmlOut += '<a data-eng="text" data-fr="text" data-ger="text">test</a><br>';       
    }
}

document.getElementById('demo').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', htmlOut);
```

Comment: Pretty good bet  that `"text"` is just a placeholder for what i'm guessing are translations

Comment: probably.  its hard to say without knowing which cms, but it certainly sounds like placeholder text for some existing translation plugin of that cms.  meh, Im just treating my boredom with regexes, ;)

Comment: Thanks so much @Rooster, it looks promising. I will give it a shot and let you know how it works :) I would not normally attempt something like this but the plugin is very rigid and would be so difficult to fix its output... a jQuery attempt is just a last resort

Comment: @charlietfl I agree.  just giving op a glean of a possible solution.  didnt want to make it too detailed, rather, just show the concept.